# Mozilla Firefox no me reconoce decimal con punto en input number

Tags: html, jquery, firefox, bootstrap-tags-input

Tengo un inconveniente con mozilla firefox; no me reconoce cuando ingreso un numero decimal con **punto** en un input number. ( ejem si ingreso 2.5 no acepta, pero si acepta 2,5 )

```
<input type='number' step='any' max='"+producto.cantidad+"' class='form-control' id='cantidad"+contador+"' name='"+contador+"cantidad' value='1' onchange='cantidadVariable("+contador+")' required>
```

El input lo agrego con jquery a mi formulario y lo valido con bootstrap. Al tratar de enviar falla la validacion de bootstrap del formulario (mensaje: 'ingrese un numero').

MOZILLA FIREFOX

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CHROME

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(necesito que me permita ingresar con punto)

Comment: la etiqueta de idioma, en qué idioma está? <html lang="(idioma)">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuve ese error alguna vez, la manera en la que yo lo resolví, fue agregando una etiqueta `lang` a esos inputs, de esta manera:

```
<input type="number" lang="en">
```

Con eso ya no debería darte problemas

Comment: esto es la solución, gracias gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con `step='0.1'` asi:

```html
<input type='number' step='0.1' max='"+producto.cantidad+"' class='form-control' id='cantidad"+contador+"' name='"+contador+"cantidad' value='1' onchange='cantidadVariable("+contador+")' required>
```